# How to do a time based animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation, frame-rate

I wanted to rotate Rectangle by 360 degree in 10 seconds. And also I want to apply different frame rate to it for example 5 fps, 10 fps etc. But no matter what frame rate is, rectangle should rotate in 10 seconds.

So please tell me how can I control fps of animation? 
Which animation method I should use?

I am using following method.
Suggest any other good method to do it.
Thanks in Advance.

```
public class Square extends View  {

private Rect rect;
private Paint paint;
float height1;
float width1;

public Square(Context context)
{

 super(context);
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 ((Activity)      getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
  int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
 int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
 height1=height;
 width1=width;

Point cos = new Point(width/2,height/2);
 int left = cos.x-(200);
int top = cos.y - 200;
 int right =cos.x+200;
 int bottom = cos.y+200;

 rect = new Rect(left,top,right,bottom);

 // create a rectangle that we'll draw late rect = new Rect(x, y,  sideLength, sideLength);

 // create the Paint and set its color
paint = new Paint();






 }


 protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {


 super.onDraw(canvas);
  /* canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);*/
  //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  long time1 = System.nanoTime();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);


 // border
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

 long ti = animate().getDuration();
 String x = "hello";

//Log.e("Tag",x+ti);

long lsttime = System.nanoTime();
double fps = 100000000.0 / (lsttime - time1);
animate().rotation(360).setDuration(10000).start();


String fpss = "" + fps;
Log.e("Tag", fpss);
}

 }
```

Comment: Show us..what you have tried so far ??

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(YOUR_LAYOUT, View.ROTATION_Y, 0.0f, 90f, 180f, 360f);
rotate .setDuration(10000); //10sec
rotate .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

You should use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). Interpolator describes the way the animation done, look at youtube at all the possibilities.

Comment: How can I control Fps with this??

Comment: it has nothing to do with FPS. You can control the changes-by-time. FPS is Frames-per-second you should NEVER change the default unless you are optimizing graphic for some complicate game

Comment: My time is constant i.e 10 sec. And i am using canvas to draw rectangle  and  animate() method to rotate it.

Comment: this is what you achieve by setDuration in my example